# OR combine two lookaheads

Tags: c#, regex

I am successfully chaining two negative regex (C#/.NET) lookaheads to exclude `<html>` tags that contain ' amp' or ' ⚡':

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nnzf4g/1)

```
<\s*?html((?!.*?\samp[\s>])(?!.*?\s⚡[\s>]).*?)>
```

But I was searching for a possibility to **OR combine** the two searches, something like `[amp|⚡]`:

```
<\s*?html((?!.*?\s[⚡|amp][\s>]).*?)>
```

Is that possible, and if so, what would be the correct syntax?

**EDIT:** I had an error in the initial question, because it didn't show quite what I wanted to capture: everything after html up to >, if it doesn't include amp or ⚡. Now the statements are right and also the regEx101. And a good solution has also been commented, that is to use () instead of []. So my current working solution is:

```
<\s*?html(
  (?!
    .*?
    \s(⚡|amp)[\s>]
  )
.*?)>
```

Comment: This seems to work: `<html((?!(.*)? (amp|⚡)[ >]).*?)`

Comment: sometimes the solution is so close and you don't see it. thanks @lancylot2004

Comment: Note that `.*` will not work if the tag is split on multiple lines.

Comment: Consider not using regex for parsing html

Comment: @DanielA.White I've heard that before: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4335480](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4335480). But it works for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is using a group instead of a character class, but the pattern also has a few unnecessary parts.

- You can remove `.*?` at the end as it will not match anything because it is optional, and adds nothing to the assertion.
- You can remove the parenthesis here `(.*)?` including the question mark as the `.*` is already optional
- You can remove the whole outer capturing group because the pattern inside it does not match anything.

If there are no further angle brackets after the opening `<html` you can write it as:

```
<html(?![^<>]* (?:amp|⚡)[ >])
```

**Explanation**

- `<html` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[^<>]*` Optionally match any char except `<` and `>`
  - `(?:amp|⚡)[ >]` Match a space, either amp or ⚡ followed by either a space or `>`
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aIUXrN/1)